# Regular expression to match last number in a string

Tags: regex, string

I need to extract the last number that is inside a string. I'm trying to do this with regex and negative lookaheads, but it's not working. This is the regex that I have:

```
\d+(?!\d+)
```

And these are some strings, just to give you an idea, and what the regex should match:

```
ARRAY[123]         matches 123 
ARRAY[123].ITEM[4] matches 4
B:1000             matches 1000
B:1000.10          matches 10
```

And so on. The regex matches the numbers, but all of them. I don't get why the negative lookahead is not working. Any one care to explain?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Your regex `\d+(?!\d+)` says

match any number if it is not ***immediately followed*** by a number.

which is incorrect. A number is last if it is ***not followed (following it anywhere, not just immediately) by any other number.***

When translated to regex we have:

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

[**Rubular Link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/fQHTdkCKLI)

Comment: +1, this is much cleaner than my `(?:\D|^)` mess ;-) (and closer to the OP's original regex too)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I haven't realized that I needed to include the .* to be *not just immediately*.

Comment: Was banging my head against the desk on this one. Thank you for an elegant solution

Comment: Love this solution, because it's a good starting ground for any other "last x in string" needs. The format is `(regex)(?!.*(regex))` Personally I like looking for any decimal numbers so the regex I often use is: `((?:\d*\.)?\d+)(?!.*((?:\d*\.)?\d+))`

Comment: That's nice! But how do I match an expression that starts after the last digit but before a specific word? `f1rst number 77, 2 substring-that-I-need before KEYWORD 3 asd 555`? I would like to get this part `substring-that-I-need before `

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
.*(?:\D|^)(\d+)
```

to get the last number; this is because the matcher will gobble up all the characters with `.*`, then backtrack to the first non-digit character or the start of the string, then match the final group of digits.

Your negative lookahead isn't working because on the string "1 3", for example, the `1` is matched by the `\d+`, then the space matches the negative lookahead (since it's not a sequence of one or more digits). The `3` is never even looked at.

Note that your example regex doesn't have any groups in it, so I'm not sure how you were extracting the number.

Comment: Just curious, why the `(?:\D|^)` bit of your regex? Doesn't `.*` handle it just fine?

Comment: @jb: Heh, I started out with that then had to delete my answer while I came up with `(?:\D|^)`. The problem with `.*(\d+)` is that only the last single digit will be matched (since the engine stops as soon as the regex is satisfied, which it will be after backtracking one digit character)

Comment: If you somehow anchor from the beginning of the string as with your `.*`, you need your `(?:\D+^)`, or equivalently, `[\D\A]`. If you anchor from the end of the string, you do not need it, as in codaddict or my answer.

Comment: @sawa: Ooh, `\A`, I always forget about those anchors. Unfortunately, my Python 2.6 chokes on it when it's in a character class together with `\D`

Answer (score 11):

I took it this way: you need to make sure the match is close enough to the end of the string; close enough in the sense that only non-digits may intervene. What I suggest is the following:

```
/(\d+)\D*\z/
```

1. `\z` at the end means that that is the end of the string.
2. `\D*` before that means that an arbitrary number of non-digits can intervene between the match and the end of the string.
3. `(\d+)` is the matching part. It is in parenthesis so that you can pick it up, as was pointed out by Cameron.

Comment: I don't know `\z` and it doesn't seam to work (javascript). I use `$` instead: `/(\d+)\D*$/`

Answer (score 0):

I still had issues with managing the capture groups
(for example, if using `Inline Modifiers (?imsxXU)`).

This worked for my purposes -

```
.*(?:\D|^)\d*(\D)
```