# Incrementing the last digit in a Python string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'd like to increment the last digit of user provided string in Python 2.7.

I can replace the first digit like this:

```
def increment_hostname(name):
    try:
        number = re.search(r'\d+', name).group() 
    except AttributeError:
        return False            
    number = int(number) + 1
    number = str(number)
    return re.sub(r'\d+', number, name)
```

I can match all the digits with re.findall then increment the last digit in the list but I'm not sure how to do the replace:

```
number = re.findall(r'\d+', name)     
number = numbers[-1]
number = int(number) + 1                      
number = str(number)
```

Comment: How about `number.replace(number[-1],str(int(number[-1])+1))`

Comment: `\d$` will match a digit at the end of the string.

Comment: Barmar: The digit usually won't be at the end of the string since I'm dealing with hostnames. I just want the last of however many are in the list.
sshashank: I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: So `host009` should become...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson good point, I've updated the answer - might help the OP.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`negative look ahead`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to see that there are no digits after a digit, pass a function to the [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) replacement argument and increment the digit in it:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo 123 bar"
>>> re.sub('\d(?!\d)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), s)
'foo 124 bar'
```

You may also want to handle `9` in a special way, for example, replace it with `0`:

```
>>> def repl(match):
...     digit = int(match.group(0))
...     return str(digit + 1 if digit != 9 else 0)
... 
>>> s = "foo 789 bar"
>>> re.sub('\d(?!\d)', repl, s)
'foo 780 bar'
```

UPD (handling the new example):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "f.bar-29.domain.com"
>>> re.sub('(\d+)(?!\d)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), s)
'f.bar-30.domain.com'
```

Comment: If there are two sets of numbers this will increment both of them.
Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question but I want to be able handle names such as foo1.bar-2.domain.com and increment the 2. In cases with one set of number I don't have to limit the substitution to the last digit so f.bar-29.domain.com could become foo.bar-30.domain.com.  Thanks for the tip about negative look ahead that is very helpful.

Comment: @Merch good, check the `UPD` section - I've slightly modified the regex to handle the case.

Comment: @alecxe For your UPD, if you want to increment ONLY the last number, you need (\d+)(?!.*\d) as found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5320864/3571110.  Your regex will increment all numbers found. So f.3bar-29.domain.com would become f.4bar-30.domain.com with (\d+)(?!\d) and f.3bar-30.domain.com with (\d+)(?!.*\d)

Comment: @proximous thanks for sharing that worked perfectly for my needs. Saved me alot of trouble with bumping just last digit in varying digit group lenths including ones with letters.

```
last_tag = 'v2.6.32.27'
new_tag = re.sub(r"(\d+)(?!.*\d)", lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), last_tag)
```

Results in: v2.6.32.28