# how can i turn "11 12 13 14" to "12 13 14 15" by using re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

It is easy to convert `11 12 13 14` to `11a 12a 13a 14a`, using:

```
myStr = "11 12 13 14"
myStr = re.sub(r'(\d*)', r'\1a', myStr)
print myStr # 11a 12a 13a 14a
```

but how can I turn `11 12 13 14` to `12 13 14 15`  by using `re.sub`?

Comment: Is `re.sub` a requirement? Regex substitution isn't generally suited for things like incrementing numbers.

Comment: You can use a [**callback for re.sub**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094975/python-re-sub-question)

Comment: `' '.join([str(int(s) + 1) for s in myStr.split()])` would be much easier (and considerably more readable) than faffing around with regular expressions.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible in general.  This would require manipulating numbers (adding one to each of them), but regular expressions don't know about numbers (they know about symbols used to write them - 0123..., but don't know that they are different than say abcd...)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Off topic: many thanks for introducing me to the word _faffing_.

Comment: Related : [Is it possible to increment numbers using regex substitution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941362/is-it-possible-to-increment-numbers-using-regex-substitution)

Comment: @Matthew: See answer below, of course it is possible.

Comment: This [*Incrementing the last digit in a Python string*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820883/incrementing-the-last-digit-in-a-python-string) is very close.

Comment: @Jan I stand corrected.  It isn't possible to do with regular expressions on their own, as I stated, but I wasn't aware that Python allowed a callback function to be passed to the sub function like that.

Comment: @Matthew: Right you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex solution with `re.sub()`:

```
import re
string = "11 12 13 14"

def repl(m):
    number = int(m.group(1)) + 1
    return str(number)

print re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\b', repl, string)
# 12 13 14 15
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/U0NPsV).

<sup>As others mentioned, this might not be the most appropriate solution though.</sup>

Comment: thanks alot~   this is my first quetion on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach for a string that only contains integer numbers separated with space is

```
s = "11 12 13 14"
print(" ".join([str(int(x)+1) for x in s.split()]))
# => 12 13 14 15
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/jcFGQx)

An alternative with a `re.sub` can be used with the help of a `\d+` regex pattern and a lambda in the replacement part:

```
import re
s = "11 12 13 14"
res = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1), s)
print(res) # => 12 13 14 15
```

[Another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/cJ27bw)

The advantage of the regex approach is:

- You can increment number *inside larger texts* containing words, punctuation, etc.
- You can enchance/further precise the pattern to only increment number in *specific context* (like, only increment numbers followed with `$` with `\d+(?=\$)` or that are not part of float values with [`(?<!\d\.)\b\d+\b(?!\.\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/iY7oD2/1))