# Add one to end of alphanumeric string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to efficiently add one to the end of a string like this:
`tt0000001` --> `tt0000002` but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

A complicated way of doing this is to remove the 2 t's at the beginning, count the number of non-zero digits (let's call that number z), make the string an int, add 1, and then create a string with 2 t's, 6 - z 0's, and then the int, but since I need to use many strings (ex: `tt0000001`, then `tt0000002` then `tt0000003`, etc) many times, it would be great to have a more efficient way of doing this.

Would anyone know how to do this? A one-liner would be ideal if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Someone else had the same problem - so look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-increment-suffix-number-in-string/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing the last digit in a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820883/incrementing-the-last-digit-in-a-python-string)

Comment: s = `"tt" + str(int(s[2:]) + 1).rjust(7, '0')` where `s ="tt0000001" `

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is essentially correct. It's not as difficult as you suggest, though, as creating a 0-padded string from an integer is supported.

As long as you know that the number is 7 digits, you can do something like

```
>>> x = 'tt0000001'
>>> x = f'tt{int(x.lstrip("t"))+1:07}'
>>> x
'tt0000002'
```

Even simpler, though, is to keep just an integer variable, and only (re)construct the label as necessary each time you increment the integer.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x += 1
>>> f'tt{x:07}'
'tt0000002'
>>> x += 1
>>> f'tt{x:07}'
'tt0000003'
```

Comment: Good solution, I used a regex in mine, but yours is way better! :)