# howto extract last number in ansible variable

Tags: regex, ansible

I have variable, its version numbering. How I catch last number in version

example

```
app_ver: 1.5.0.0.20

- debug:
    var: app_ver | regex_search('^(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)$') | list
```

gives me

```
"app_ver |regex_search('^(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+)$') | list": [
        "1",
        ".",
        "5",
        ".",
        "0",
        ".",
        "0",
        ".",
        "2",
        "0"
    ]
```

I need last number, may be 1-figure or more

Comment: try `regex_search('\.(\d+)$')` in place of `regex_search('^(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)$')`. This will give you ".20" but do not convert it to `list`.

Comment: Can you use (\d+)(?!.*\d) as shown here : [regular expression get last number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320525/regular-expression-to-match-last-number-in-a-string)

Comment: if ansible supports look-arounds then I would suggest `regex_search('(?<!\.)(\d+)$')` This should give just `20`.

Answer (score 11):

Split the line by `.` and take last element:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ app_ver.split('.')[-1] }}"
```

Comment: If I have a `var: mango-apple-banana-orange` and if I were to split and combine everything except banana, would that be possible via ansible?
Desired output: `mango-apple-orange`

I have been trying different ways using `var.split('-')[-2] | join('-')` , cannot seem to tell ansible to ingore the 3rd element. Thoughts pls?